# Log java exception on docker swarm + fluentd

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, docker-swarm, fluentd

I made a configuration in my swarm cluster to use fluentd to send the logs to elasticsearch. This part is working perfectly, however the exception logs of my java images appear every stack line in a record.
I have already tried using the detect_exceptions and multiline plugin, but it seems to me that they only work when the source is "tail" type (in my case it's "forward").

My stack.yml

```
version: '3.6'

....

services:

  myjavaservice:
    image: myjavaservice
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        tag: myjavaservice
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role==worker]
      replicas: 1

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.2
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 10M
        max-file: 1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == manager

  fluentd:
    image: my.repo/fluentd
    volumes:
      - ./Logs:/fluentd/log
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      update_config:
        delay: 2s
.....
```

And my fluentd.conf

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<filter *>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"
    tag ${tag}
  </record>
</filter>

<label @raw>
  <match myapp.*>
    @type detect_exceptions
    remove_tag_prefix myapp
    message log
    languages java
    multiline_flush_interval 0.5
  </match>

  <match *>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host elasticsearch
      port 9200
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix logstash
      logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
      include_tag_key true
      tag_key @log_name
      flush_interval 1s
    </store>
  </match>
</label>
```

Could you tell me if it's possible to do this (put the entire exception stack in a record) using logging-driver fluentd on swarm?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks okkez.
I was able to solve the problem using the concat plugin, but I'm going to test this solution you passed too.
Here's the solution I've implemented:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<filter **>
  @type concat
  key log
  stream_identity_key container_id
  multiline_start_regexp /^\S+/
  flush_interval 1s
  timeout_label @processdata
</filter>

<label @ERROR>
  <match **>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</label>

<label @processdata>
  <match **>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</label>

<match **>
  @type elasticsearch
  logstash_format true
  host elasticsearch
  port 9200
  index_name fluentd
  type_name fluentd
  flush_interval 5s
</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following snippet is helpful(not tested):

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
  @label @INPUT
</source>

<label @INPUT>
  <filter>
    @type record_transformer
    <record>
      hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"
      tag ${tag}
    </record>
  </filter>

  <match myapp.*>
    @type detect_exceptions
    remove_tag_prefix myapp
    message log
    languages java
    multiline_flush_interval 0.5
  </match>
  <match>
    @type relabel
    @label @OUTPUT
  </match>
</label>

<label @OUTPUT>
  <match>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host elasticsearch
      port 9200
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix logstash
      logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
      include_tag_key true
      tag_key @log_name
      flush_interval 1s
    </store>
  </match>
</label>
```

it is the point that defines internal routing using `@label`.

If you want to concatenate stack trace in one record, you can use [fluent-plugin-concat](https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat).